# Altering a column: null to not null

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, null, alter-table, alter-column

I have a table that has several nullable integer columns.  This is undesirable for several reasons, so I am looking to update all nulls to 0 and then set these columns to `NOT NULL`. Aside from changing nulls to `0`, data must be preserved.

I am looking for the *specific SQL syntax* to alter a column (call it `ColumnA`) to "`not null`".  Assume the data has been updated to not contain nulls.

Using *SQL server 2000*.

Comment: One other thing - you might want to add a default to that any existing inserts that don't specify the column don't fail: ALTER TABLE FOO ADD CONSTRAINT FOO_Bar_Default DEFAULT 0 FOR Bar

Comment: Also you may be surprised to know that [under some circumstances](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/29600/3690) altering a column to `NOT NULL` can cause a lot of logging.

Answer (score 2212, accepted):

First, make all current `NULL` values disappear:

```
UPDATE [Table] SET [Column]=0 WHERE [Column] IS NULL
```

Then, update the table definition to disallow "NULLs":

```
ALTER TABLE [Table] ALTER COLUMN [Column] INTEGER NOT NULL
```

Comment: Let me value-add to the above two correct responses. The semantics of NULL can have a few meanings. One of the common meaning is UNKNOWN.
Take SCORE as an example. A null SCORE and a ZERO SCORE is a world of difference! Before you did the above recommendations. Make sure you application does not take null in its business logic.

Comment: Backup your database first in case you make a typo and your DB explodes.

Comment: Databases should always be backed up.  You never know when one of your people might write and UPDATE or DELETE statement and forget the WHERE clause.

Comment: I know the question was for SQLServer, but this didn't quite work for Postgres 9.  Instead using try: "ALTER TABLE [Table] ALTER COLUMN [COLUMN] SET NOT NULL"

Comment: @SebastianGodelet: there's a setting that allows you to turn off that warning, or make it so that it doesn't prevent you from modifying the table. In some cases, changing the schema of a table requires that a new table be created, the data copied over from the old and the old table dropped. Because an error in this process could result in data loss, SSMS warns you and, by default, prevents you from doing it.

Comment: do  you have to re-type the column (say i dont want to look them all up) or can i just omit that part?

Comment: For Oracle sql 
    ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY (columnname type NOT NULL);

worked for me

Comment: I would also specify a column default value of (0). This would prevent existing code that doesn't specify the col value to not break and produce the intended inserted value.

Answer (score 66):

I had the same problem, but the field used to default to null, and now I want to default it to 0.  That required adding one more line after mdb's solution:

```
ALTER TABLE [Table] ADD CONSTRAINT [Constraint] DEFAULT 0 FOR [Column];
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the problem. The default is already set, it's the NOT NULL which needs to be changed. With only your answer, all existing records will stay NULL and the problem remains.

Comment: Did you read the part about "adding one more line"? As in, this is in addition to the above answer?

Comment: Actually, no it's not clear that "adding one more line" means "in addition to the above answer" (especially since there are many answers "above") - if that's what you meant, then the wording really needs to change and you should include the line of the answer you refer to

Comment: Just wanted to chime in and say that it's a good idea to explicitly name your constraints, defaults included. If you ever need to drop a column you'll have to know the name of the constraint to drop before you'll be able to. Ran into this in our DB migrations a few times. I know the example includes it here, but it's still a place some devs trip up because the name is not required.

Answer (score 41):

You will have to do it in two steps:

1. Update the table so that there are no nulls in the column.

```
UPDATE MyTable SET MyNullableColumn = 0
WHERE MyNullableColumn IS NULL
```

2. Alter the table to change the property of the column

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable
ALTER COLUMN MyNullableColumn MyNullableColumnDatatype NOT NULL
```

Comment: `SET MyNullableColumn = 0` only works if your existing column is a numeric column. For non-numeric types you need to set another default value like and empty string or default date, etc. But this answer is fully relevant to the above-mentioned question and correct ;-)

Answer (score 31):

For Oracle 11g, I was able to change the column attribute as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY columnname datatype NOT NULL;
```

Otherwise abatichev's answer seemed good. You can't repeat the alter - it complains (at least in SQL Developer) that the column is already not null.

Comment: It appears that in Oracle 11, you don't have to repeat the `datatype`. Merely `columname NOT NULL` is enough. See [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_3001.htm#SQLRF53129).

Answer (score 22):

this worked for me:

```
ALTER TABLE [Table] 
Alter COLUMN [Column] VARCHAR(50) not null;
```

Answer (score 15):

As long as the column is not a unique identifier

```
UPDATE table set columnName = 0 where columnName is null
```

Then

Alter the table and set the field to non null and specify a default value of 0

Answer (score 5):

In case of `FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT`... there will be a problem if '0' is not present in the column of Primary key table. The solution for that is...

**STEP1:**

Disable all the constraints using this code :

```
EXEC sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all"
```

**STEP2:**

```
RUN UPDATE COMMAND (as mentioned in above comments)
RUN ALTER COMMAND (as mentioned in above comments)
```

**STEP3:**

Enable all the constraints using this code :

```
exec sp_msforeachtable @command1="print '?'", @command2="ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT all"
```

Answer (score 4):

this seems simpler, but only works on Oracle:

```
ALTER TABLE [Table] 
ALTER [Column] NUMBER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL;
```

in addition, with this, you can also add columns, not just alter it.
It updates to the default value (0) in this example, if the value was null.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I had difficulties with the posted answers. I ended up using the following:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE COLUMN column_name column_name VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '';
```

Change `VARCHAR(200)` to your datatype, and optionally change the default value.

If you don't have a default value you're going to have a problem making this change, as default would be null creating a conflict.

Answer (score 1):

Making column not null and adding default can also be done in the SSMS GUI.

1. As others have already stated, you can't set "not null" until all
   the existing data is "not null" like so:

`UPDATE myTable SET myColumn = 0`

2. Once that's done, with the table in design view (right click on
   table and click "design view"), you can just uncheck the *Allow
   Nulls* columns like so:

[image]

3. Still in design view with the column selected, you can see the
   *Column Properties* in the window below and set the default to 0 in there as well like so:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can change the definition of existing DB column using following sql.

```
ALTER TABLE mytable modify mycolumn datatype NOT NULL;
```

Comment: I needed to use 'alter column' ('modify' didn't worked)

Answer (score 1):

Let's take an example:

```
TABLE NAME=EMPLOYEE
```

And I want to change the column `EMPLOYEE_NAME` to `NOT NULL`. This query can be used for the task:

```
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE MODIFY EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_NAME datatype NOT NULL;
```

Comment: how to do this for multiple columns?
for example, making employee_name and employee_email not null simultaneously?

What is the syntax? Below syntax gives error
***alter table employee
alter column employee_name varchar(20) not null,
alter column employee_email varchar(20) not null;***

Answer (score 0):

For the inbuilt javaDB  included in the JDK (Oracle's supported distribution of the Apache Derby) the below worked for me

```
alter table [table name] alter column [column name] not null;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First make sure the column that your changing to not does not have null values
   select count(*) from table where column's_name is null
2. Impute the missing values.  you can replace the nulls with empty string or 0 or an average or median value or an interpolated value.  It depends on your back fill strategy or forward fill strategy.
3. Decide if the column values need to be unique or non-unique.  if they need to be unique than add an unique constraint.  Otherwise, see if performance is adequate or if you need to add an index.