# Can I add a not null column without DEFAULT value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Can I add a column which is I specify as NOT NULL,I don't want to specify the DEFAULT value but MS-SQL 2005 says:

> ALTER TABLE only allows columns to be added that can contain nulls, or have a DEFAULT definition specified, or the column being added is an identity or timestamp column, or alternatively if none of the previous conditions are satisfied the table must be empty to allow addition of this column. Column 'test' cannot be added to non-empty table 'shiplist' because it does not satisfy these conditions.

If YES, please let me know the syntax, if No please specify the reason.

Comment: I think the point of this is so that the column can be added as 'NOT NULL' but specify what the value should be for the existing columns and not having to do anything cute like creating a constraint then dropping it.  Seems reasonable to me to want to have the NOT NULL, no default, but just specify what the value should be for existing rows.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

No, you can't.

Because if you could, SQL wouldn't know what to put as value in the already existing records. If you didn't have any records in the table it would work without issues.

The simplest way to do this is create the column with a default and then remove the default.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable ADD
MyColumn text NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_MyTable_MyColumn DEFAULT 'defaultValue'
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable
DROP CONSTRAINT DF_MyTable_MyColumn
```

Another alternative would be to add the column without the constraint, fill the values for all cells and add the constraint.

Answer (score 30):

Add the column to the table, update the existing rows so none of them are null, and then add a "not null" constraint.

Comment: This is a better solution than create/drop the default, if the logic for the new values is more complex than a simple constant.

Comment: Why, or how, is it possibly better to update (manually?) + changing to "not null, instead of "updating" automatically through default + changing to "no default" (dropping default)?

Comment: @vgv8 - what if the new values in each row depend on other columns already in the row? You can't express that via a default constraint.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, see my reply http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997966/can-i-add-a-not-null-column-without-default-value/4003967#4003967 . I had to provide a variant of am answer in order to gain the reason to engage better formatting

Comment: To learn how to add a "not null" constraint, check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/689766/138757

Answer (score 10):

I use this approach to insert NOT NULL column without default value

```
ALTER TABLE [Table] ADD [Column] INT NULL
GO
UPDATE [Table] SET [Column] = <default_value>
ALTER TABLE [Table] ALTER COLUMN [Column] INT NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 9):

No - SQL Server quite reasonably rejects this, because *it wouldn't know what value existing rows should have*

It's easy to create a DEFAULT at the same time, and then immediately drop it.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Just use empty string `''` (in case of character type) or 0 (if numeric), etc as DEFAULT value

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot. But you can consider to specify the default value to ('')

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't, as SQL Server, or any other database engines will force this new column to be null for existing rows into your data table. But since you do not allow a NULL, you are required to provide a default value in order to respect your own constraint. This falls under great sense! The DBE will not extrapolate a value for non-null values for the existing rows.

Comment: While what you say does make sense, it is not true of at least one "database engine" being MS Access, which allows a `NOT NULL` column to be added to a table without also specifying a `DEFAULT`, the result of which is null values in a `NOT NULL` column. I'll provide proof as an answer...

Answer (score 0):

@[Damien_The_Unbeliever's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997966/can-i-add-a-not-null-column-without-default-value/3998009#3998009) , 
Is it adding computed column?  Neither question nor answer implied anything like that. In case of computed column the error states:

> "Only UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY constraints can be created on computed columns, while CHECK, FOREIGN KEY, and NOT NULL constraints require that computed columns be persisted"

OK, if to continue this guessing game, here is my script illustrating the adding of "NOT NULL" column in one "ALTER TABLE" step:

```
CREATE TABLE TestInsertComputedColumn 
(
    FirstName VARCHAR(100),
    LastName CHAR(50)
);  

insert into TestInsertComputedColumn(FirstName,LastName)
     select 'v', 'gv8';
select * from TestInsertComputedColumn;

ALTER TABLE TestInsertComputedColumn 
      ADD FullName As FirstName + LastName PERSISTED NOT NULL;

select * from TestInsertComputedColumn;
--drop TABLE TestInsertComputedColumn;
```

Answer (score 0):

I used below approach it worked for me

```
Syntax:
ALTER TABLE <YourTable> ADD <NewColumn> <NewColumnType> NOT NULL DEFAULT <DefaultValue>

Example:
ALTER TABLE Tablename ADD ColumnName datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE();
```

Answer (score 0):

As an option you can initially create Null-able column, then update your table column with valid not null values and finally ALTER column to set NOT NULL constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD STAGE INT NULL
GO
UPDATE MY_TABLE SET <a valid not null values for your column>
GO
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ALTER COLUMN STAGE INT NOT NULL
GO
```