# use current date as default value for a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to set the default value of a column to `DateTime.Now` in Sql Server?

Example:

```
table Event
Id int (auto-increment) not null
Description nvarchar(50) not null
Date datetime not null
```

The line:

```
Insert into Event(Description) values('teste');
```

should insert a row and the Date value should be the current date.

Comment: This link may be useful  too - http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/05/10/sql-server-adding-column-defaulting-to-current-datetime-in-table/

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Add a default constraint with the GETDATE() function as value.

```
ALTER TABLE myTable 
  ADD CONSTRAINT CONSTRAINT_NAME
    DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR myColumn
```

Comment: In PostgreSQL it would be: 
"alter table myTable add column mydatecol date default now();" .. i only add this comment since the Sql-Server is not mentioned in the question's title. Might help a PostgreSQL user...

Comment: This would be the form if the column already exists in the table, and it has no constraint to set a default value if the value is omitted in INSERT statements (or from CURSOR inserts).

Comment: The way this is written, it looks like it's missing the `CONSTRAINT` keyword. It should be  `...  ADD CONSTRAINT MY_CONSTRAINT_NAME ...`

Comment: Does `GETDATE()` give us the UTC time?

Answer (score 32):

```
CREATE TABLE Orders(
    O_Id int NOT NULL,
    OrderNo int NOT NULL,
    P_Id int,
    OrderDate date DEFAULT GETDATE() // you can set default constraints while creating the table
)
```

Comment: This form sets an unnamed constraint. It is best to name the constraint: `[...]OrderDate DATE CONSTRAINT DF_Orders_date DEFAULT GETDATE()[...]`

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
Insert into Event(Description,Date) values('teste', GETDATE());
```

Also, you can change your table so that 'Date' has a default, "GETDATE()"

Answer (score 5):

**I have also come across this need for my database project.  I decided to share my findings here.**

1) There is no way to a NOT NULL field without a default when data already exists ([Can I add a not null column without DEFAULT value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997966/can-i-add-a-not-null-column-without-default-value))

2) This topic has been addressed for a long time.  Here is a 2008 question ([Add a column with a default value to an existing table in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92082/add-a-column-with-a-default-value-to-an-existing-table-in-sql-server))

3) The DEFAULT constraint is used to provide a default value for a column.  The default value will be added to all new records IF no other value is specified.  (https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_default.asp)

4) The Visual Studio Database Project that I use for development is really good about generating change scripts for you.  This is the change script created for my DB promotion:

```
GO
PRINT N'Altering [dbo].[PROD_WHSE_ACTUAL]...';

GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PROD_WHSE_ACTUAL]
    ADD [DATE] DATE DEFAULT getdate() NOT NULL;
```

-

Here are the steps I took to update my database using Visual Studio for development.

1) Add default value (Visual Studio SSDT: DB Project: table designer)
[image]

2) Use the Schema Comparison tool to generate the change script.

```
code already provided above
```

3) View the data BEFORE applying the change.
[image]

4) View the data AFTER applying the change.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

To use the **current date** as the **default** for a date column, you will need to:

**1-** open table designer

**2-** select the column

**3-** go to column proprerties

**4-** set the value of **Default value or binding** propriete To (**getdate()**)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Select Table Column Name where you want to get default value of Current date

```
 ALTER TABLE 
 [dbo].[Table_Name]
 ADD  CONSTRAINT [Constraint_Name] 
 DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [Column_Name]
```

Alter Table Query

```
Alter TABLE [dbo].[Table_Name](
    [PDate] [datetime] Default GetDate())
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution that seems to me much easier to remember :

```
alter table table_name add column date datetime default current_timestamp
```

Answer (score 0):

Table creation Syntax can be like:

```
Create table api_key(api_key_id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) 
PRIMARY KEY, date_added date DEFAULT 
GetDate());
```

Insertion query syntax can be like:

```
Insert into api_key values(GETDATE());
```

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the table and click on Design,then click on column that you want to set default value.

Then in bottom of page in column properties set Default value or binding to : 'getdate()'