# SQL. Changes require the table to be recreated

Tags: sql-server, sql-drop

There is a table full which contains data. Is it possible to change field from [not null] to [null] without dropping and recreating it? 
SQL writes that table have to be dropped and recreated. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Altering a column: null to not null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/689746/altering-a-column-null-to-not-null)

Comment: Which database are we talking about? SQL is just a query language, it doesn't specify which database you are using. Examples; MySQL, MSSQL, PostgreSQL etc.

Comment: You shouldn't be using the visual designer - it's rather limited in many ways. Learn how to express those modification with T-SQL and execute them as statements in your Mgmt Studio - there's really no need to drop the table for this change....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try:

```
alter table YourTable alter column YourColumn int null
```

Per Martin Smiths comment, a change in nullability does not require a copy of the table.  On disk, each row has a [nullabiltiy bitmap](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Design+and+Theory/67552/) at the start.  I thought the bitmap had to be resized in some cases, but apparently it contains a bit for each column, nullable or not nullable.

Comment: The last part isn't true. The `NULL_BITMAP` contains a bit for all columns regardless of nullability. [Even adding a new 9th,17th etc column doesn't require this.](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/Misconceptions-around-adding-columns-to-a-table.aspx)

Comment: @MartinSmith: Thanks, misconception indeed.  This links to the [full article](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/Misconceptions-around-null-bitmap-size.aspx)

Comment: I wanna add one interesting comment. There is also an option in SQL Server menu. Just remove a tick from Options\Designer "Prevent saving changes that require table recreation".

Comment: @Anton Will this not drop and recreate the table and loosing the data in the process?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use `ALTER TABLE XXX ALTER COLUMN YYY YOURTYPE NULL` command?

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

```
ALTER TABLE [Table] ALTER COLUMN [Column] [YourDataType] NULL
```