# Alter NVARCHAR column from NULL to NOT NULL in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've created a table column called RateValue with initially allowing NULL value but I want to make it NOT NULL. I used **SQL Server 2008 R2**

I tried the following but it does not work

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.AAElement
ALTER COLUMN RateValue NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
```

Comment: Do you have any rows in this table? If you do you must first make sure that you have no row with a NULL value in RateValue.

Comment: what's the error message you get ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Altering a column: null to not null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/689746/altering-a-column-null-to-not-null)

Comment: "Not working" usually means "you did not read the message". Read it because it tells you what is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most likely problem is pre-existing `NULL` values.

Get rid of the `NULL` values first, then alter:

```
UPDATE AAElement 
SET RateValue = ''
WHERE RateValue IS NULL
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.AAElement
ALTER COLUMN RateValue NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
```

Otherwise the constraint is violated as it's being created.