# Entity Framework object reference not set when getting data from table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
command = "INSERT INTO clients VALUES(" + NameTB.Text +")";
objCtx.SaveChanges();

List<Client> clients = new List<Client>();
clients = objCtx.ExecuteStoreQuery<Client>("Select * from clients").ToList();

string x = "";
for (int i = 0; i < clients.Count; i++)
     x += clients[i].Name.ToString();//exception here

MessageBox.Show(x);
```

I just start to work with EF and have no idea how to fix this; I took the code from [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/Querying-with-EDM.aspx)

Comment: Warning !!! SQL Injection

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the `Name` property is null in the `Client` data that is returned.

Either have a constraint in the database that this field is required or add a null check:

```
string x = "";
for (int i = 0; i < clients.Count; i++) {
     if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(clients[i].Name)) {
          x += clients[i].Name.ToString();
     }
}
```

Also, if you're going to work with many clients and your string is going to get big I suggest you take a look at [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: how do I add a constraint in the database?

Comment: @MihaiBratulescu Which database are you working with?

Comment: mdf, is that what you are asking for?

Comment: @MihaiBratulescu Isn't that SQL or something ? take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/689746/altering-a-column-null-to-not-null

Comment: I just noticed I forgot to execute the SQL command so there is no data in the table so my question now is why is the length on the list 3 and not 0?

Comment: @MihaiBratulescu Don't know, I can't see your list :) If it's 0 length before the query and 3 after then something does come back.

Comment: all list entries are null and no INSERT query was ever executed, I'm not at work anymore but thanks for your time