# create primary key on existing table without primary key in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, primary-key

I am trying to assign an existing column to be the primary key(and another in different table as foreign key) in a table without primary key. I tried this:
[Altering a column: null to not null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689746/altering-a-column-null-to-not-null), and it didn't work. The column contains number, text and null values.

Could someone create a step-by-step guide and share with everyone here?

This is the error message:

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 13, Line 2
>   String or binary data would be truncated.

It would great if you can help interpret the error message.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you already have a column that you want to be your primary key (which has unique values and no nulls) or do you want a new column? By the way, you DON'T want to follow the steps in the link you provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add a primary key to an existing table you can do this:

```
ALTER TABLE yourTableName ADD yourColumnName INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1)
```

which will add a new column and automatically populate it with unique integer values starting from one. To add a foreign key to another table use similar syntax to above but don't make the column NOT NULL until you've worked out how to link it to your existing primary key - which is a whole different question.

```
ALTER TABLE yourOtherTable ADD yourFKColumnName INT WITH CONSTRAINT [FK_SensibleForeignKeyName] FOREIGN KEY ([yourFKColumnName]) REFERENCES yourTableName([yourColumnName])
```

I haven't tested it but that should be pretty close to what you need.

Comment: I found 10 null values in the column I want to use as the primary key. Don't think I can drop those. Is creating a new column to be the primary the only option now? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: If the column that you want to use has any duplicate values or nulls then you won't be able to use it. Primary key must be non null and unique.

Answer (score 1):

Just do a

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_YourTable
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (YourColumnHere)
```

and you're done. This requires that `YourColumnHere` is a **non-nullable** column, of course.

Comment: I found 10 null values in the column I want to use as the primary key.