# When Can Columns in Table not be Altered and not be Added?

Tags: sql

i seem to be getting paranoid over 2 cases listed below. Can someone provide a general list of conditions for:

1. when can columns not be added to an existing table
2. when can columns not be altered

Please skip the reason for same name for either case.

Comment: Dont have idea what are you asking. Are you talking about alter table permision?

Comment: Which DBMS are you talking about?

Comment: no, my concern is about general design for database.

Comment: I am working with SQL Server Management Studio at the moment but i thought same would be apply for oracle

Comment: by the way, why the negative votes right away?

Comment: I still havent add negative vote yet, but your question doesnt make sense. In desing you can `add/alter`all the column you want. please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
   And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: For example: In below linked post 

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/689746/altering-a-column-null-to-not-null

Answer (score 0):

When can these things not happen? 
When the user trying to do them doesn't have permissions. Users should in general never have these permissions.(incidentally developers should not have prod permissions to do this sort of thing, so that all changes must be deployed with a script that is in source control)
In SQL server, you also have DDL triggers that can be set up to prevent changes