# How to update null value to zero?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want make a update query in sql-server which can update any null value to zero in a table.

Comment: Use: `UPDATE mytable SET myfield = 0 WHERE myfield IS NULL`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Altering a column: null to not null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689746/altering-a-column-null-to-not-null)

Comment: Why? Null values make sense. If you don't understand them, learn how to deal with them!

Comment: Btw, _mycolumn_, not _myfield_...

Comment: @jarlh The reason is irrelevant, OP asked for a question and needs an answer ^^.

Comment: @YassineBadache, OP has a problem - whatever it is - and is perhaps doing something completely wrong.'

Comment: @jarlh Yes, he has a problem. About this problem, he wants to make an update in SQL Server, which can update any `null` value to zero in a table. Could you provide OP with such an answer ?

Comment: @YassineBadache, don't be such a smarty*ss.

Answer (score 1):

This basic request will do it:

```
UPDATE <Table> SET <Column to update> = 0 WHERE <Column to update> IS NULL;
```

NB: Capital letters are not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Try IFULL()

```
SELECT IFNULL(column_name, 0) FROM table_name;
```

Comment: It is ISNULL in SQL Server/MS SQL