# Add NOT NULL to a column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following column

```
 `Equipamento_Solucao_id` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
```

I would like it to be

```
`Equipamento_Solucao_id` VARCHAR(32) DEFAULT NULL,
```

How can I do this without changing my database model, that is, with a sql query?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Altering a column: null to not null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689746/altering-a-column-null-to-not-null)

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: mysql workbench

Comment: Not to be too pedantic, but the DBMS you are using is mysql. MySQL Workbench is the development environment you are using to interact with the DBMS.

Answer (score 1):

You would use an `alter table` statement.  A typical method would be:

```
alter table t alter column Equipamento_Solucao_id VARCHAR(32) DEFAULT NULL;
```

You could also look through the system tables on your database, find the not-null constraint, and then drop it specifically.