# Adding a new NOT NULL column to an existing Table with data

Tags: sql, mysql, alter-table

I want to add a new `NOT NULL` column to an existing table which has data in MySQL 5.7. I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689746/altering-a-column-null-to-not-null) and I am using the solution suggested there.

I am adding the new column as `NULL`, populate data for the new column and then change the column from `NOT NULL` to `NULL`.

```
-- 1. add new column as null
ALTER TABLE `mytable` ADD COLUMN newCol BIT NULL AFTER curCol;

-- 2. populate default data for new column
SET sql_safe_updates = 0;
UPDATE `mytable` SET newCol = 0;
SET sql_safe_updates = 1;

-- 3. change the column to NOT NULL
ALTER TABLE `mytable` ALTER COLUMN newCol BIT NOT NULL;
```

But I am getting the following error on the last command:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'BIT NOT NULL:' at line 1

Comment: This worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/689782/10204932

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This piece of SQL is not valid in MySQL:

```
ALTER TABLE `mytable` ALTER COLUMN newCol BIT NOT NULL;
```

Instead, consider :

```
ALTER TABLE `mytable` MODIFY newCol BIT NOT NULL;
```

Reference : [MySQL `ALTER TABLE` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html)

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in three steps:

1. Add your new column *(initially, let it have `NULL` values)*

   ```
   ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN new_col datatype NULL AFTER cur_col;
   ```
2. Update the table so that there are no `NULL` in our new column

   ```
   UPDATE my_table SET new_col = 0 WHERE new_col IS NULL;
   ```
3. Modify our new column to `NOT NULL`

   ```
   ALTER TABLE my_table MODIFY COLUMN new_col datatype NOT NULL;
   ```

Reference: [StackOverflow- Altering a column: null to not null](https://stackoverflow.com/a/689782/10204932)