# How to drop a column default value 'NULL' in Azure Data Studio And add a new constraint on the same column for primary key

Tags: sql, azure, azure-data-studio

I have a table in database (Azure Data Studio)and while writing the create table script I forgot to add the primary key constraint. In order to add primary key constraint I have to alter the table and before that the default NULL has to be removed from that particular column tow which I am going to mark as primary key.

My create table scripts looks like this:
Crete Table dbo.employee(
employeeID varchar(120) NULL,
employeeName varchar(50) NULL,
employeePhone Integer NULL
)

So I need to create a primary key constraint on employeeID table in Azure Data Studio so I was using the general script like:

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[employee] ADD PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
[employeeID ] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

The above statement is giving me expected error because the **employeeID **is set to NULL as default.The error I am getting while alter the column is this:[enter image description here][enter image description here][1]
Can anyone help me to resolve this issue and add the primary key on that column.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Altering a column: null to not null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689746/altering-a-column-null-to-not-null)

Comment: Is the table empty? Does `employeeID` contain alphabetic characters, or only digits? Consider `INTEGER` as the data type for `employeeID` if you only have digits. It is faster by orders of magnitude.

Comment: The table is not empty, it is n varchar datatype column

Comment: ALTER TABLE dbo.employee ALTER COLUMN employeeID varchar(120) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE dbo.employee ADD CONSTRAINT PK_employee PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (employeeID);

Comment: This script is also not working, and giving me error as below: cannot define primary key constraint on nullable column in table 'dbo.employee'

Comment: Share the error

Comment: I added the screenshot in the question itself now, you can check once!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Try to execute the query one by one.
First execute `ALTER TABLE dbo.employee ALTER COLUMN employeeID varchar(120) NOT NULL; ` 
Then execute `ALTER TABLE dbo.employee ADD CONSTRAINT PK_employee PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (employeeID); `

Answer (score 0):

A primary key cannot have a null value.  It is used to enforce data integrity and ensure that each row in the table is unique. In SQL Server, you can define a primary key column as NOT NULL to ensure that it does not allow null values. If you try to insert a row with a null value in the primary key column, you will get an error.

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.employee ALTER COLUMN employeeID varchar(120) NOT NULL;
```

Then try to add the primary key constraint statement `employeeID` column using the ALTER TABLE statement.

**Reference:** MS document on [Primary Key constraint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-primary-keys?view=sql-server-ver15#add-a-primary-key-constraint-to-a-table)